# importing KafkaSource doesn't work in Google Cloud scala shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I try to import this library inside ssh console in Scala Shell on Google Cloud:

```
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource
```

I installed flink before:

```
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/flink/flink-1.14.4/flink-1.14.4-bin-scala_2.11.tgz
tar -xzf flink-1.14.4-bin-scala_2.11.tgz
```

but when I run the import line I get this error:

```
<console>:81: error: object kafka is not a member of package org.apache.flink.connector
       import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource
```

what could be the problem? I have a correct flink and scala version. I need this to get data from kafka inside flink.

(but in Intellij import works great...)

Answer (score 0):

Flink doesn't come with the Kafka connector. You need to add that to your classpath manually

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka

> in Intellij import works great

Are you using Maven/SBT/Gradle ? Then sounds like you've included the above package as a project dependency, and you should bundle your code as an uber JAR and upload it to GCP, rather than simply using the Scala REPL